# Why doesn't The Ascension have color TV's?

Tags: ascension

Color TV was introduced to the US in 1953 (according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_television)).

But throughout the series all we can see are black and white TV's. Is there an explanation (in universe or out) to why the state-of-the-art* spaceship has no color TVs?

I haven't got a screen cap but when the monitor in the bridge

> intercepts Alf

it's in black and white. I would have expected it to be in color as it was produced in color.

<sub>* I'm assuming is was supposed to be state-of-the-art as the government would have put a lot of money into it..</sub>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this [review by ScifiStorm](http://scifistorm.org/2014/11/09/ascension-syfy-launch-back-into-space-based-drama/) puts it very nicely, the ship (as portrayed by Sea to Sky Studios) is a hodge-podge of both futuristic and anachronistic technology, *styled* on 1960s tech but not completely beholden to it.

> Technology-wise they seem to be right as well. Using early 1960s
>   technology as the basis, you see black and white monitors, reel video
>   recorders with poor resolution, mechanical devices with large lighted
>   buttons, etc. But there are refinements as well. The elevator itself
>   appears futuristic. They have “video cartridges” which look like they
>   could be something like USB drives (but perhaps contain recording tape
>   similar to 8-track or the more modern DLT/LTO data formats).
>
> And apparently while on board in the 1973 they created the Stenotab,
>   which eventually evolves to look suspiciously like a thick
>   iPad…presumably there are manufacturing and fabrication systems on
>   board, but being able to advance to modern computer technology I would
>   expect to be very difficult if not impossible. Especially without any
>   input from Earth. Theoretically Earth can send information to
>   Ascension, but if they were halfway to Proxima, it would take two
>   years to reach it…so technical data (say, perhaps, for the transistor
>   and how to fabricate it) could be sent, but conversations and advice
>   based on current events would be impossible.

You may also wish to note that [real-world space programs](http://astroblog.cosmobc.com/2010/03/27/did-you-know-the-space-shuttle-runs-on-only-one-megabyte-of-ram/) have always tended to lag behind consumer technology. Missions are often planned years, if not decades in advance and there's no overwhelming need to use the latest technology when existing solutions can be found.

Comment: They also lag behind so that consumers do a lot of the robustness testing I suspect :)

Comment: @Dreamwalker - Yes, very much so. Also when there are multiple dependencies, switching to a new solution can push a project back months due to the need to ensure that everything down the chain is also compatible.

Comment: There is also a tendency in Aerospace to utilize technology that is well established with long track records or for robustness. For example, the RCA 1802 was used for many space missions, it was older and less advanced than chips being used to run talking dolls and calculators at the time, and it was under-clocked to 25% of it's intended speed, but it was very robust. Assembly technology for spacecraft and other aircraft is decades behind the processes being used for automobiles.

Comment: The show implied that many of our own developments actually came _from_ the experts on board Ascension.